# copy exe hex/binary to another exe and run both when the user click

Tags: c#, exe

```
byte[] bytesF = File.ReadAllBytes("G:\\finish.exe");
byte[] bytesC = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\copy.exe");

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
      ms.Write(bytesF, 0, bytesF.Length);
      ms.Write(bytesC, 0, bytesC.Length);
      File.WriteAllBytes("G:\\finish.exe", ms.ToArray());
}
```

using c#

the function work and when i check the hex (hex workshop) i see the both program.

**finish.exe** - it a regular exe (for example a game but in my program its a cmd that print hello)

**copy.exe** - it's open a file on the desktop.

the problem is when i run the file finish it open just the first file
and i want to open both program in one click.

how can i do it? thanks...

Comment: I think you have to make question more clear.

Comment: You can't do it like that. Programs have defined entry points where the code starts running. You'd need a wrapper to call the entry points sequentially.

Comment: I don't think that you can run both executables simply by appending their bytes and hoping it will execute. Write a batch file that will execute both simultaneously. (Just use notepad)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how executable's work they have a defined structure, you can't just concat them together and expect them both to run.

Your best option is some sort of stub that extracts the executables from say resources to a temporary directory and runs them both from there and waits on both of them to terminate before exiting itself.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: @yonatan No it's not an "answer" type of answer, more of a "full book" type of answer, if you tell us what you are trying to do and why, we may be able to suggest better and simpler alternative (don't tell us about the technical micro problem you're trying to fix, but about the actual use case you're trying to cover, i'm sure something better can be done)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau
Basically I'm trying to learn C #
And I did in Windows from it can open a new window At the push of a button

Then I tried to do it in the console application.
I'm trying to do now just one software program that copies the software second.
Then we'll run the first software also runs other ...

For example, a program developed in cmd and write 'hello', then software opens a new text file on the desktop.